# Array only has data inside event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox which calls my event handler

```
<Form.Check label='Januar 2019' id='jan19' onChange={handleCheck} />
<Form.Check label='Februar 2019' id='feb19' onChange={handleCheck} />
```

this is the handleCheck function

```
 function handleCheck (event) {
    // create the array with the valid months for 2019
    if (event.target.id === 'jan19' && event.target.checked) validMonths2019.push('01')
    if (event.target.id === 'feb19' && event.target.checked) validMonths2019.push('02')
}
```

And this the array

```
 const validMonths2019 = []
```

If console.log it inside the handleCheck function it is filled with data. But outside of the function is empty. How can I fix this? I need to send this array with a post request later on

```
useEffect(() => {

if(buttonValue === 'create') {
  // Reset the state of the stateful components
  setAlertValue(null)
  setLoading(true)
  setStatus(null)
  // here the array is emtpy..
  console.log(validMonths2019)
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:5000/', {
      contractId: contractId,
      contractCompletionQuote: contractCompletionQuote,
      iterations: iterations,
      validMonths2019: validMonths2019
    })
```

Comment: we need more code to be able to help you...

Comment: Just added more code.

Comment: You need to declare the validMonths2019 variable at a place where it will be visible due to scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and set validMonths2019 as an array in the state using hooks:

```
const [ validMonths2019, setValidMonths2019 ] = useState([]);
```

Then you can do a handler so it does not reset every time you change it:

```
handleAddMonth = (newValue) => {
    const newArray = [ ...validMonths2019 ];
    newArray.push(newValue);
    setValidMonths2019(newArray);
}
```

That way you will have the data stored in the state and you'll be able to use it whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `validMonths2019` value in your component state.

Do this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [validMonths2019, setValidMonths] = useState([])

  function handleCheck (event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'jan19' && event.target.checked) setValidMonths([...validMonths2019, '01'])
    if (event.target.id === 'feb19' && event.target.checked) setValidMonths([...validMonths2019, '02'])

    // Note: You might want to clean this up a bit to handle removing values from `validMonth2019` if the user un-checks the checkbox 
  }

  return (...)
}
```

What I would ultimately recommend though is that you make the checkbox components controlled, like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [validMonths2019, setValidMonths] = useState([])

  function handleCheck (val) {
    const newValidMonths = [...validMonths2019] // copies state so that it can be worked with before updating the state using the set method
    if (!validMonths2019.includes(val)) {
      newValidMonths.push(val)
      setValidMonths(newValidMonths)
    }
    else { // This is to remove it from state incase the user un-checks the checkbox
      newValidMonths.filter(v => v !== val)
      setValidMonths(newValidMonths)
    }
  }

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Form.Check label='January 2019' id="jan19" checked={validMonths2019.includes('01')} onChange={() => handleCheck('01')} />
      <Form.Check label='February 2019' id='feb19' checked={validMonths2019.includes('02')} onChange={() => handleCheck('02)} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have one problem with this solution, the first checkbox i check will get ignored, the rest of them work. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure, I've added a more robust solution to my answer that might be worth checking out.

Comment: I implemented your new answer, however If something is checked it cannot be unchecked. Any idea on that?

Comment: Ah right, sorry man. I've updated my answer again in an attempt to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var validMonths2019 = [];
function handleCheck (event) {
    // create the array with the valid months for 2019
    if (event.target.id === 'jan19' && event.target.checked)    validMonths2019.push('01')
    if (event.target.id === 'feb19' && event.target.checked) validMonths2019.push('02')
}
```